# Set relative path for a log4j2 log file

Tags: java, spring, log4j, log4j2

I am using log4j2 for logging with this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="LogToFile" fileName="tomcat.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.say" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.springframework.boot" level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

As you can see line relevant for defining file to which the logs will be written to is:

```
<File name="LogToFile" fileName="tomcat.log">
```

And with this I cannot find any logs in the project folder. When I used the absolute path, I succeeded to produce the log file, but I want it to be based on the project path, and I've seen examples of this path being something like: `logs/app.log` so I guess it is possible to set it, I am just not sure why it doesn't work for me.

This is a spring boot project run on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: If you use `logs/app.log` , the log file is created under the `logs` folder, relative to the process working directory. You can find out what that folder is by calling `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Comment: @Daniele Thats it, thank you! I found my logs in the `/opt/eclipse/eclipse`. Is there any way to put log file in in the project folder without hardcoding the path to the project?

Comment: Well, usually in Eclipse the working folder is the base project folder (where the code is) so it should already be set to the project folder? You can check the working directory for your run config under "run configurations> (your java application) > arguments > working directory".

Comment: @Daniele For some reason the work dir was set to `/opt/eclipse/eclipse` by default, but now I changed it to the project folder. Thanks again! You can post that answer if you want and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If you just specific the file name it should just create the `.log` file in your project root directory. For example if the base of your project root is `c:/mycode/myproject` then the log file should be created in the `myproject` directory.

If you specifically want the file to be placed in a `log` sub-directory you can just specify that as part of the `filename` attribute ...  `fileName="./logs/tomcat.log"`. The file would then be placed in `c:/mycode/myproject/logs`

From the config you've supplied I don't see anything that should not work like this. The only thing is that your `LogToFile` appender is only applied globally to `error` level logging and nothing below `info` specifically for classes part of the `com.say` package. So anything that is not part of the `com.say` package or is lower than `error` level would not be logged to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I would try :

```
"./logs/tomcat.log"
```